# SQL how to compare two columns from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables, in which table 1 contains 4 columns while table 2 contains 8 columns. I have two columns in table1 that I want to compare them with two columns in table2.

```
Table 1 have column1 and column2 (that needs to be compared)
Table 2 have column6 and column7 (that needs to be compared)
```

I need to compare the combination of the two columns. I tried to do the below query however it doesn't work

```
Select * from table1 
where column1, column2 NOT IN (Select column6, column7 from table2)
```

How can I compare the two columns in the the two tables?

Comment: Do you want to select all rows from t1 where t1.column1 <> t2.column6 and t1.column2 <> t2.column7?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server and/or MySQL? (Don't tag different dbms products not used!)

Comment: Give some example data to demonstrate the behaviour you need, I can interpret your post in several different ways.

Answer (score 3):

Except shows the difference between two tables (the Oracle guys use minus instead of except and the syntax and use is the same). It is used to compare the differences between two tables. For example, let's see the differences between the two tables

```
SELECT * FROM
 table1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM
 table2
```

Comment: I used this method to great success.  However, I wish there was a way to highlight the exact value & column where the data was different? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try a minus statement. This will give you any results from the first select statement of table1 that aren't in the second select statement on table2.

```
select column1, column2 from table1
minus
select column6, column7 from table2
```

Answer (score 2):

`NOT EXISTS` is a "null safe" version of `NOT IN`.
If you mean the combination column1 AND column2 not in same row in table2:

```
select *
from table1
where NOT EXISTS (select 1 from table2
                  where table1.column1 = table2.column6
                    and table1.column2 = table2.column7)
```

Or if you mean just column1 and column2 values can't even be in different rows in table2:

```
select *
from table1
where NOT EXISTS (select 1 from table2
                  where table1.column1 = table2.column6)
  and NOT EXISTS (select 1 from table2
                  where table1.column2 = table2.column7)
```

Answer (score 0):

The query with the least comparisions I can think of is

```
Select t1.* 
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.column1 in (t2.column6, t2.column7)
                    or t1.column2 in (t2.column6, t2.column7)
where t2.column6 is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *  FROM table1 t1
RIGHT JOIN table2 t2
WHERE
t1.c1 = t2.c6 AND
t1.c2 = t2.c7
```

Comment: Although this may answer the questions, you may wan't to provide some extra details and explain the answer. In it's current state this answer is low-quality.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query:

```
 Select 
     case when (table1.column1 = table2.column6) 
         then 1 else 0 
     end column1_6 check, 
     case when (table1.column2 = table2.column7) 
         then 1 else 0 
     end
 from 
     table1 
 inner join
     table2 on table1.ID = Table2.ID
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    select * from table1 where column1 not in(select column 6 from table2) or column2 not in(select column7 from table2)
```

This will give you rows from table1 where there are differences between col1 and col6 or col2 and col7

Hope this helps