# MySQL: Check count of columns in one table against value in column of second table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, comparison

while this sounds similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886856/sql-how-to-compare-two-columns-from-two-different-tables), it has a little more involved.  what I'm trying to do is check is the number of column entries in table 1 is equal to the stored value in column 2.  to whit:

```sql
table1:
+------+--------------+
|  id  |  isComplete  |  VARCHAR, TINYINT
+------+--------------+
|  20  |  true        |
|  20  |  false       |
|  20  |  true        |
+------+--------------+

table2:
+------+--------------+
|  id  |  numJobs     |  VARCHAR, TINYINT
+------+--------------+
|  20  |  3           |
+------+--------------+
```

so the idea is basically to check if the number of `isComplete === true` (2) is equal to the `numJobs` (3) value.

here's what i started with:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE id = 20
AND isComplete = true
AND LIKE (SELECT numJobs FROM table2 WHERE id = 20);
```

all I need is a true/false return, but I'm stuck. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry: i provided EXACTLY the code i'm working with complete WITH tables.  how  doesn't this qualify as a minimal example?

Comment: The accepted answer at the link provided explains all that in some detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data type of the column `isComplete` is `BOOLEAN` or `INTEGER` (`0` or `1`) then you need to check the sum of the column:

```
SELECT SUM(t1.isComplete) = (SELECT t2.numJobs FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id) result
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.id = 20
```

The expression:

```
SUM(t1.isComplete) = (SELECT t2.numJobs FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id)
```

will evaluate to `0` or `1`.

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p1r9gptKTA67nNamtDaSMF/1).
Result for your sample data:

```
| result |
| ------ |
| 0      |
```

Comment: this looks like the simplest and more readable implementation to ME, no offense @Mureinik.  i'll give it a run and confirm.  thank you.

Comment: `isComplete` is a `tinyint`.  and this returns `NULL` whether `isComplete` are all true or not.  :(

Comment: @WhiteRau The BOOLEAN data type is just an alias of TINYINT(1). Check this demo to see that the code works:https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p1r9gptKTA67nNamtDaSMF/0

Comment: yeah.  i'm taking a peek.  and i'm looking at my stuff and i can't figure out why i get `NULL` as they are identical (just a few more columns in each table, but that's irrelevant as we're not matching to those).

Comment: Check it: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p1r9gptKTA67nNamtDaSMF/2

Comment: FMP.  somehow the trailing `result` didn't get copied over... what a dumbass i am!  yep.  this works great.  thank you.  now just have to wait for the timer to expire so i can mark it answered.

Answer (score 1):

`true` and `false` act as `1` and `0` in a numerical context. So you could sum the `isComplete` column and join it on `table2`:

```sql
SELECT table2.*
FROM   table2 t2
JOIN   (SELECT   id, SUM(iscomplete) AS sic
        FROM     table1
        GROUP BY id) t1 ON t2.id = t1.id AND t2.numjobs = t1.sic
```

Comment: but how do i check for a specific ID number?  this seems to check everything...

Comment: @WhiteRau you can add a where clause: `where t2.id = 20`

Comment: oh, just tack it at the end?  ok.  i'll give it a whirl.  thanks.  :)